# C++ matrix computation efficiency

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, matrix, eigen

We are trying to optimize our C++ code and the we have the following matrix computation (using the Eigen library)

```
#include<Eigen/Dense>

int main(){

   MatrixXd P = MatrixXd::Random(30,30); // a  random double 30 x 30 matrix P
   MatrixXd M = MatrixXd::Random(30,30); // a  random double 30 x 30 matrix M
   Matrix<double, 30, 30> I; 
   I.setIdentity(); // I is an 30 x 30 identity matirx

   P = (I-M)*P

   return 0;

   }
```

Where they are all nxn matrices and I is the identity matrix. 
   We found the rewriting the above matrix computation

```
   P= (I- M)*P
```

as

```
   P = P-M*P
```

results in ~4-8x speed up in a Linux ubuntu system using a gcc 6.2 compiler. I realize the fact that the compiler might not know anything about identity matrix and the fact I*P = P, but still cannot wrap my head around what makes the efficiency improve so much. Anyone knows the possible reasons that make such substantial improvements?

Comment: I'm no expert, but using only P, M sounds like better cache-behaviour than using I,M,P. Sadly these kind of optimizations are very complex (given some target architecture) and i assume that the actual size of your matrices (and maybe the internal type) matter here too!

Comment: The second version probably matches with a single function call with no temporaties, like `dgemm` http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dgemm.f.html  and the first doesn't match with a single function, so it does that computation with temporaries (first computing `I - M` and then multiplying by `P` and replacing the old value of `P`.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] otherwise we are just guessing.  Also post your platform and how you compiled it.  Posting your disassembly would also be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I include some more code!

Comment: would you please compile your file with this command in both cases and compare the assembly file (.s) compile command (g++ -O2 -S foo.c)

Comment: What do you mean by 'GNC compiler'? Gnu C++ compiler maybe? (i.e. g++) If so, which version are you using? (might actually not be relevant here, but you should generally mention that for questions about performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `I.identity();` does not exist. What you want is either `I.setIdentity()`, or `P = (MatrixXd::Identity(30,30)-M)*P`.
If you use the first option, Eigen will definitely need to do a full 30x30 subtraction of `I` and `M` (it would be very hard for a compiler to see the equivalence to your second expression). Overall, this will result in two temporaries (one for the difference, one for the product).

If you actually used `I.Identity()` you are calling a static function like a member function, and your compiler should at least warn you about that. This will not actually modify `I` and you end up with uninitialized values in `I`, which likely will include some NaN or denormal values, both can be bad for floating point performance. And of course your result would be wrong.

Overall, I'd think the easiest ways to write your equation are

```
P -= M*P;
```

or

```
MatrixXd Pnew = P - M*P;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake (yes it should be setIdentity(), was trying to edit post on a mobile device, big mistake) and your explanation. I modified my post.